# cx_Oracle is failing to import in Python 3.9, despite everything being pathed properly and all requisite parts running on 64bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, cx-oracle, python-3.9

To preface, we have a 2.7 install of Python running in a venv, that works with cx_Oracle no problem. I've been tasked with getting a new machine up and running with Python 3.9 and an integral part of our code library is cx_Oracle as that's how we speak to the Oracle Tables we use.

Per SQL Developer our database is as follows.

> ```
>  Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64 bit Production
>  Pl/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
>  CORE12.2.0.1.0Production
>  TNS for Linus: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
>  NLSRTL Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
> ```

Per PyCharm I'm running in our VENV

> cx_oracle 8.2.1

I've seen an entry here where capitalization was an issue, however I double checked that when importing through Anaconda, and within File Explorer cx_Oracle is properly capitalized, I think the Python Interpreter section within PyCharm just formats all output in lowercase.

As far as Instant Client goes, we were using 12.1 on our Python 2.7 install, but for upgrading to 3.9 I tried to bring us forward into the present (also pretty sure the 12.1 install was 32 bit). I've tried with both:

> instantclient_19_12

and

> instantclient_21_3

both using the 64bit basic download from Oracle's website.

Whenever I try to

```
import cx_Oracle
```

I get the dreaded

```
ImportError: DLL Load failed while importing cx_Oracle: The specified module could not be found.
```

Now I'm working with legacy code that I had no input in writing but our 2.7 install is working with this function to set PATH and the like.

```
currdirr = os.getcwd()
instantClientPath = "/instantclient_19_12/"
os.environ["PATH"] = currdir + instantClientPath+";"+os.environ["PATH"]
os.environ["ORACLE_HOME"] = instantClientPath
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = instantClientPath
os.environ["TNS_ADMIN"] = instantClientPath
os.environ["NLS_LANG"] = "american_america.WE8MSWIN1252"

import cx_Oracle
```

Previously in our 2.7 install `instantClientPath` was the same with just `/instantclient_12_1/` the folders that are being pointed to are in the same parent directory.

However someone said that if you were using cx_Oracle ver 8 or higher you need to be using a different method to initialize so I switched to trying

```
import cx_Oracle
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"C:\Our_Python_Directory\instantclient_19_12")
```

Either way, I get the same ImportError, with no actual indication as to which .dll it's failing to find. Best I can tell from basically living on google for the last week trying to fix this is that it's a problem with `oci.dll`, but that is present.

Additionally, per Windows.

> System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
> Edition Windows 10 Pro
> Version 21H1

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you installed the VS Redistributable required by your version of Instant Client?

Comment: I believe that this version requires 2017 my machine has two copies of 2015-2019...its the first time I've ever seen a multi year version like that, but I couldn't find anything on if that served as 2017 or if I explicitly needed 2017 alone.

Comment: Tried to install vc redist 2017, and the installer told me my machine already has it, so I guess 2015-2019 does cover it,at least in Microsoft's opinion.

Comment: Set the environment variable `DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL` to the value 64 and then retry the operation. Post the output in your question.

Comment: Also worth trying the 12.1 installation that you know works with Python 2.7. The same should work with Python 3.9.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga, I got a working situation before I saw your posts (first time I've had the opportunity to get back to this with our workflow/holiday). Do you still need me to post that output even though my code is now working with my solution? Additionally if you could point me at something that explains the importance/why it matters for the cx_Oracle.pyd, I'd really appreciate that. Unfortunately the 12.1 Instant Client did not work with my Python 3.9 install, that not working was actually what started the initial Instant Client hunt.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found. In our previous project directory we had a file called `cx_Oracle.pyd` as well as the Instant Client folder for `instantclient_12_1`. As long as those two things were present our directory seems to work on all of our remote machines, even if the machine in question doesn't have cx_Oracle installed in the venv or an Instant Client install, besides the files in the project directory.

So on the new machine in the location where cx_Oracle was installed by Anaconda in the venv, I found a file called `cx_Oracle.cp39-win_amd64.pyd`, moving this file into my project directory, suddenly allowed cx_Oracle to recognize the dlls in the Instant Client folder, and I was able to access my database with no problem. I don't know why this worked, I'm gonna try and dig further to find out why, but I'm leaving this here in case anyone else has a similar issue.